# Test framework quit unexpectedly in Clion

Tags: c++, googletest, clion

Trying to run simple TEST using GTest in Clion.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(a, b) { ASSERT_EQ(1, 1); }

int main() { return 0; }
```

Always getting message "Test framework quit unexpectedly.".

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Valera)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(Valera main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(googletest-master)
include_directories(googletest-master/googletest/include)
include_directories(googletest-master/googlemock/include)
target_link_libraries(Valera gtest gtest_main)
```

Comment: Why are you defining `main` if you are also linking `gtest_main`? That would just cause a duplicate symbol for `main`. This could be your issue.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you.